# Which words are used by Pandavas to address Dhritarashtra and Gandhari?

Tags: mahabharata

Yudhishthira, Bhima, Arjuna, Nakula and Sahadeva are the names of Pandavas.

Pandu is the father of Pandavas. Kunti is mother of Yudhishthira, Bhima and Arjuna. Madri is mother of Nakula and Sahadeva.

Dhritarashtra is the elder brother for Pandu and Gandhari is a wife of Dhritarashtra.

In Mahabharata, which relationship term is used by Pandavas to address Dhritarashtra and Gandhari?

Comment: They called him Jyesth Pitashree ( like Bade Papa ) senior father